# How to handle not supported MIME type on azure datactory?

Tags: azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to implement a pipeline on azure data-factory where a I get access to datas from ODATA. Taken these I implement a pipeline where azure DF copies these on a blob storage. For what concerns access and permissions there is no problem. The issue rises up when I want to get a preview of what I'm going to store inside my blob storage. The reported error is:

```
A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the content type of the response. None of the supported type(s) ...
```

Don't ask me more about data because we have privacy issues to deal with and answer only if you have something concrete to share. Thank You in advance

Comment: Are you sure your credentials and network access is correct - it sounds like you may be getting an error response and the payload cannot be parsed by ADF.

Comment: Eh I know.... we are trying to find it out sending our request to the customer in order to check this possibility. Until this we cannot know