# MIME type not supported on Azure Data Factory ODATA

Tags: odata, azure-data-factory

I decorated my Controller class with [Produces("application/json")] to enforce JSON output, but did not help.

Did you find a solution to this issue? I get the same error with the same scenario, but intermittently. The user however get the same error consistently.

[How to handle not supported MIME type on azure datactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59173492/how-to-handle-not-supported-mime-type-on-azure-datactory)

Comment: To get the best answer, I suggest you call the Azure  Support.  According my experience, they will tell you if it could be solved.  If you don't know how to ask Azure Support for help, write down the steps as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Leon. I was able to resolve the issue. My ODATA API (Multi-Tenant App) was in a different Tenant and the Data Factory was in a different Tenant. In my API, the ValidateIssuers was set to true and the ValidIssuers was assigned correctly - array of valid tenants. Even then this was breaking it. I set the ValidateIssuers to false and wrote my custom logic to validate the issuers. This pretty much fixed it. There was another error related to the Audience. The AAD resource property in the Data Factory Linked Service (Connection) should match the ODATA Api AD applications Application ID URI – it is case sensitive. In all these scenarios, the error was always the MIME error which was throwing me off – completely misleading. I had to do some logging in my ODATA Api to get to the actual issue.

Comment: Congratulations, you can mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According my experience and I searched a lot, we can't find any solutions to solve the problem. I'm afraid we can't answer you.

So I suggest that you can call the Azure Support for help , maybe they could some more effective suggestions or solution.

You could follow these steps On Portal:

[image]

New support request:

[image]

Fill the details about you problem:
[image]
[image]

Then create the request, Azure Support will email or call you later.

Hope this helps.